# Python f-strings: indentation for long strings?

Tags: python, indentation, f-string

I'm facing (aesthetic) problems with long f-string expressions in Python. For example, this code snippet

```py
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    x_true = 3
    x_prov = 4

    assert x_prov == x_true, f'The provided value for x, namely {x_prov}, is invalid, \
    the true value should be {x_true}!'
```

gives the following error, which is totally expected, of course:

```py
AssertionError: The provided value for x, namely 4, is invalid,     the true value should be 3!
```

There is an unwanted indentation in the error message that in my opinion looks very ugly, though. One way to circumvent this is to write

```py
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    x_true = 3
    x_prov = 4

    assert x_prov == x_true, f'The provided value for x, namely {x_prov}, is invalid, \
the true value should be {x_true}!'
    
    # Do sth else.
```

However, this also looks ugly to me, as now the second line of the string has the same indentation as the outer `'__main__'` function. Is there a way to have the AssertionError displayed properly *without* having to indent the code as the outer function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, making use of implicit string concatenation, you can do this:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    x_true = 3
    x_prov = 4

    assert x_prov == x_true, (
        f"The provided value for x, namely {x_prov}, is invalid,"
        f" the true value should be {x_true}!"
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 cases to solve your problem.

- Create an expression with brackets.
  Example:

```
(f"First part of f-string"
 f"Second part of f-string")
```

- Create a multiple string with \ separator after f-string.
  Example:

```
f"Some_part" \
f"Another part"
```